# Jquery DOB verification, inputs, with cookies "remember me"

Tags: jquery, forms, cookies, verification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I verify age using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136036/how-do-i-verify-age-using-jquery)

I need to enter the DOB and then submit the form to another page.

I think is easy but at the moment is not working.  I need the **remember me checkbox** as well.
How do I make the inputs work? 
How do I make "remember me" work? 
I think the form is correct, but needs a little help.

http://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/bhdry/33/